# No valid data sent magento product export

Tags: magento-1.9, products, export, importexport, error-message

Trying to export products from Magento using system import-export function and getting the error no valid data sent

Initially, I was trying to export a few thousand products I then tried to export just one but got the same error

[image]

Comment: Please post the error you are facing and log files.

Comment: Did you choose entity type in the dropdown? If so which one?